# Rails failing in ubuntu. Can anyone say why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

I have installed rails 2.3.5. Rails was working properly till yesterday. All of a sudden, it is throwing the following error
[image]

Here is my gem list
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check your PATH environment variable. Worst case, you could try reinstalling the rails gems.

Comment: I tried reinstalling but that didnt work. What change should I do to the PATH?

Comment: Do an `echo $PATH` and check if the directory where rails script should be install (which in ubuntu should probably be /usr/local/bin) is listed there.

Comment: The folder directory is already in PATH. :(

Answer (score 0):

Rails 2.X doesn't come with a rails command script. Try script/server.

Comment: I did create multiple projects using the same. How could I try script/server when I am not even able to create the project?

Comment: Oh yes you're right! I read your question too quickly! Sorry for that. by the way I think the only possible issue is about your bash PATH variable.